# PHP is not recognize even with the path

Tags: php, environment-variables, wampserver

I m trying to iclude PHP in my path to use in command line on windows 10.

So I add C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35; in the environemental variable path and I restart my computer.

But when i use the command : 'php -v' i get the error :
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I don't really understand what I do wrong.

[image]

Comment: NEVER EVER add PHP in WAMPServer to your path. Remember there can be many versions of PHP when using WAMPSevrer

Comment: ha why? and how do i do so?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to the Duplicate Question

Comment: I use PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.35
php -v
But i still get the same error

Comment: Did you create a little batch file like in my answer

Comment: ok i restart my computer and now it's work thank ;)